# Docker DNS Error

Tags: docker

I'm new to docker and networking. Im trying to set up a Docker container and im getting a DNS error and i have no idea where to start to resolve it.

im using this command

```
sudo docker run -name mysql -d sameersbn/mysql:latest
```

im getting this error

```
Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/sameersbn/mysql/
images: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io: no DNS servers
```

any help would be appreciated. Im running this from a server that im connect to over the network, so i internet connection and in my etc/defualt/docker file i do have the dns name servers 8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4

Comment: What do you have in the file /etc/default/docker.io ?

Comment: Can you reach other websites via wget or curl?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy ?

Comment: the problem was i started the wrong service. i did sudo service docker start instead of "sudo service docker.io start". so the right docker was not updated with my dns information.

Answer (score 1):

open command window,

`ping registry-1.docker.io`

copy the ip address and it to

`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file

`cdn-registry-1.docker.io  <ip_address>`

Restart the docker application

1. Execute "Delete Boot2Docker VM" application
2. Execute "Boot2Docker Start"

Hope this should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Use `--network host` in the command-line. Or use a docker-compose file with this option.